# ¿Como crear un fragment desde un botón?

Tags: java, android, android-fragment

Quiero que al tocar un botón se cree un fragment, la verdad he buscado mucho pero no he encontrado nada parecido, me vendría bien un poco de ayuda, gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Tienes varias opciones para empezar tienes que crear el click listener, te dejo aqui una, y si no se adapta a lo que buscas podemos mirar otra.

```
// botton es el boton que quieras que tenga la accion de click.
botton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TuFragmento puede ser el fragmento que quieras
                añadirFragmento(new TuFragmento())
            }
        }); 

private void añadirFragmento(Fragment fragmento) {
  FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
  FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
  // fragment_container es el id del contenedor donde vaya a ir tu fragmento
  fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.fragment_container, fragmento);
  fragmentTransaction.commit();
}
```

Aparte de esto te dejo un enlace a la documentacion de fragmentos:
https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments#java